# Get and assign elements in variables from a Nested List in Python

Tags: python, django, list

i'm working with a nested list in python like this list[[a,b,c,d,e],[a,b,c,d,e]]
every element is composed ever of 5 parts, the content of the list can change in amounts of elements it can be from 1 to 10 elements max.

Here came the difficult for me, cause I need to assign any part of every element into one individual variable, and when the element end, move to the next element,but before move send variables to one function that insert data in the oracle database. It is a part of a function in python django web app. The idea is to separate the data received in form a list after that send it to a stored procedure.
This is part of the code.
enter code here

```
   acomp = ''
    acomp = request.POST.getlist("acomp")      
    split_strings = []     #Here divide the list in 5 parameters that are the rows of the table in 
                           #oracle    
    n  = 5
    for index in range(0, len(acomp), n):  #Creamos una lista anidada para dividir los datos de los 
                                                   acompañantes por cada uno
        split_strings.append(acomp[index : index + n])
```

#ow I can seperate the data assign every element into a variable and send it to the function that will insert it in the database....

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can unpack each inner list like so:

```
a, b, c, d, e = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

and then do something with each variable.
You can even unpack a string like this:

```
a, b, c = 'Hey'
```